# Definition of conditional expectation given an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

The conditional expectation of a random variable $X$ given a nonnegligible event $A$ is usually defined as $\mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_A)/\mathbb{P}(A)$. How does one derive the fact that $\mathbb{E}(X|A)=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)\mathbb{P}(d\omega|A)$ where $\mathbb{P}(\cdot|A)$ denotes the regular conditional distribution?

Comment: Just apply the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: but that does not apply to the regular conditional probability distribution: I do not thing it is correct to just write $\mathbb{P}(d\omega|A)=\mathbb{P}(d\omega,A)/\mathbb{P}(A)$, unless it is given some precise meaning...

Comment: The definition uses an indicator function. $$\Bbb P(\mathrm d\omega\mid A) = \dfrac{\mathbf 1_A(\omega)\,\Bbb P(\mathrm d\omega)}{\Bbb P(A)}$$

Comment: Is this a definition or a representation theorem? Thing is, it is a random variable, due to the indicator, but it should not be, it should be a measure solely defined on the Borel sets: how would you apply it to any Borel set? The $\omega$ in the indicator seems inappropriate when evaluating e.g. $\mathbb{P}(B|A)$, which should give $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)/\mathbb{P}(A)$. But we cannot evaluate the indicator on $B$ as it is not a measure...

Comment: @Graham Kemp to be more precise, your definition works only for a discrete sample space, whereas for a general case, it cannot be right, which is the reason behind my post: everywhere I look the definition is either derived for continuous or discrete random variables with a density, but I believe a general way, regardless of the specific density, should work. Your case would not work on a random variable defined on $\Omega$ uncountable.